# Как получить доступ к библиотеке написанной на JS в приложении, написанном на Kotlin?

Tags: javascript, kotlin, openlayers

Уже достаточно много времени потерял на поиск информации в интернете, но так ничего дельного и не нашёл. Заранее благодарю за ответ

Comment: Так что у вас в наличии? Можете ли написать что у вас есть и что вам нужно более однозначно. Не то не понять на чем что написано и откуда нужен доступ

Comment: В случае `Kotlin/JS` https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-interop.html